# Netbeans curly braces formatting

Tags: netbeans, code-formatting

When i am declaring a new method in netbeans, i do as follows:

> $cursor is used to mark the position of the cursor

```
public void inc(){$cursor}
```

Then i hit enter, the output is as follows:

```
public void inc(){
$cursor}
```

What i want is as follows:

```
public void inc(){
    $cursor
}
```

How can achieve this result in netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this:

```
public void inc(){$cursor
```

then hit enter.

In short: You don't type out the second curly brace, it's generated for you together with an extra line break.